# How can i specify path value from property file in jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I want the path should not be hard coded rather be picked up from property such that we can change it according to our need.

Below Code works :---

```
@Path("ws/{version}")
public class DesignationResource {

  @PathParam("version") String version = 
              Constants.API_VERSION; //(read from property file in class Constants)
  @PathParam("servicename_designationList") String servicename_designationList=
              Constants.API_POST_CITYLIST_NAME ; //(read from property file in class Constants)



  @Path("{servicename_designationList}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDesignations()
    {
       /**
         ...CODES...
        */
    }
}
```

But if the class has two methods then its not working and throwing exception

Code: ---

```
@Path("ws/{version}")
public class DesignationResource {

  @PathParam("version") String version = 
              Constants.API_VERSION; //(read from property file in class Constants)
  @PathParam("servicename_designationList") String servicename_designationList=
              Constants.API_POST_CITYLIST_NAME ; //(read from property file in class Constants)
  @PathParam("servicename_designationListId") String servicename_designationListId=
              Constants.API_POST_CITYLISTID_NAME ; //(read from property file in class Constants)



  @Path("{servicename_designationList}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDesignations()
    {
       /**
         ...CODES...
        */
    }

  @Path("{servicename_designationListId}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDesignationsId()
    {
       /**
         ...CODES...
        */
    }
}
```

Exception recorded as :-----

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.  
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by @Consumes and @Produces annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response DesignationResource.getDesignations() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response DesignationResource.getDesignationsId() at matching regular expression /([^/]+?). These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7e5ba613', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by @Consumes and @Produces annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7e5ba613']  
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:465)  
  ...
```

Comment: What is the purpose of each method, and can you give an example URL you would send to each one

Comment: I just want my service URL controlled by property file. Suppose for calling getDesignations() URl be http://192.168.1.46:9090/api/ws/v1/designations  then some time in future i want my URL to be http://192.168.1.46:9090/api/ws/v1/desig for same purpose then i must change my property file and not my .java

Answer (score 1):

You are using same path url (servicename_designationListId) in your methods. Give different paths to your methods, like below.

```
@Path("{servicename_designations}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDesignations()
    {
       /**
         ...CODES...
        */
    }

  @Path("{servicename_designationListId}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getDesignationsId()
    {
       /**
         ...CODES...
        */
    }
```

Comment: I was using different Path Url . Updated the question problem still prevails.

Comment: Give new stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

As the stacktrace says, paths must be unique (or you use different media-types). I think, you want to do the following:

```
@Path( Constants.API_POST_CITYLIST_NAME )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response getDesignations()
{
   /**
     ...CODES...
    */
}

@Path( Constants.API_POST_CITYLISTID_NAME )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Response getDesignationsId()
{
   /**
     ...CODES...
    */
}
```

Comment: This @Path( Constants.API_POST_CITYLISTID_NAME ) is valid only when Constants.API_POST_CITYLISTID_NAME ="<some hard coded string>" and not for Constants.API_POST_CITYLISTID_NAME=property.getproperty("<propertyName>")

Comment: Yes, the value of an annotation must be a compile time constant. Therefore, I think, the only solution would be to use some kind of compile time tool (maven) to replace placeholders in your source code (class Constants) by values from a property file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the programmatic API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html) to register resources. It will allow you to register things dynamically at runtime in ways that you can't manage via Annotations.